# "The absolute uri cannot be resolved..." with JavaEE and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(1,64) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:378)
```

I have that error when trying to add tags for JSP in Eclipse EE

Using standart J2EE Preview server

Comment: Try adding the server dependencies to your classpath..Right-click on your project and then Targeted Runtimes. Make sure you have your server .jar files associated with your project.

Comment: in your jsp use uri `http://java.sun.com/jstl/core`

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause for this is a mismatch between the servlet version and jstl library you are trying to use.

If you're using servlet version 2.5 or 3.0, you should import the jstl tag lib as

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

If you're using 2.4, you should import the jstl tag lib as

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

Please show the web.xml and taglib import in your jsp. This will identify the servlet version you're using and help identify which version of jstl you should be using.

Comment: Both uri call that exection

Comment: You will need to show the jstl and servlet versions you're using - your web.xml and jsp content. You will also need to provide the list of libraries you're including in your war file.

Comment: Your web.xml shows you're using servlet spec 3.0, so you need the jstl definition of /jsp/jstl/core, and you should have jstl library version 1.2.1 available to your web app. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Answer (score 0):

Also I have jstl-1.2.jar file in WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder, and that jar added in Java Build Path -> Libaries
But I haven't JSTL in Project Facets

There is no JSTL in web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>myServlet</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: just edit the question and add the above, and remove it from answer.